# How can I hide the definition of a NixOS option in one module if it is composed by multiple ones?

Tags: nix, nixos

The use case is related to Xorg:

By default an `xorg.conf` is generated by using a template and filling in configuration values. In my setup, the option `services.xserver.config` which holds the text is defined in `<nixos/nixos/modules/services/x11/xserver.nix>` (where it is declared) and in `<nixos/nixos/modules/services/x11/hardware/synaptics.nix>`. The option is of type `line`, which means that multiple definitions are appended, interspersed by newlines, becoming a single string.

Now I want to override (in fact remove) the part generated by `xserver.nix` to get auto detection for my graphics hardware while preserving the settings by `synaptics.nix`. In other words, I want to hide the definition by `xserver.nix`, preserving all other definitions.

If I override it using `services.xserver.config = mkOverride 0 ""` then the whole content is deleted because only the definitions with the least priority are applied.

Therefore I tried disabling the xserver module and importing it again in a wrapper module, hiding the single option:

```
# xserver.nix # wrapper module
args@{ lib, pkgs, pkgs_i686, config,  ... }:

let
  super = import <nixos/nixos/modules/services/x11/xserver.nix> args;
in lib.recursiveUpdate super {
  imports = []; # the imports are not disabled recursively by disabling
                # the including module in the following:
  disabledModules = [ "services/x11/xserver.nix" ];
  config.services.xserver.config = "";
}
```

This did not change anything.

So I tried the following:

```
# xserver2.nix # wrapper module 2
args@{ lib, pkgs, pkgs_i686, config,  ... }:

let
  super = import <nixos/nixos/modules/services/x11/xserver.nix> args;
in {
  options = super.options;
  disabledModules = [ "services/x11/xserver.nix" ];
  config = lib.recursiveUpdate super.config {
    services.xserver.config = "";
  };
}
```

This didn't change anything either. Somehow the old definition still gets exported. NixOS configuration seems mysteriously stateful!?!?

Is there any possibility to achieve what I want without forking the package?

Comment: The last example has a syntax error. Are you sure you imported it properly? NixOS configuration and the module system are just Nix code, so it would be hard to make it mysteriously stateful. The module system can be both flexible and complicated, making it hard to spot the error.

Comment: When I tried it there was no syntax error but in the second snippet I posted I missed out the opening brace after the `in`. I just fixed it. I know that nix code is pure but the black magic of the module system makes it _seem_ stateful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to merges in the NixOS module system. I put your wrappers into `nix-repl` and as you say they do not override the config from `services/x11/xserver.nix`. However in `wrapper2` I altered the `config` that's passed to `services/x11/xserver.nix` and that does override the `xserver.nix` config.

```
# xserver3.nix # wrapper module 3
args@{ lib, pkgs, pkgs_i686, config,  ... }:

let
  basic.config.services.xserver = {
    enable = true;
    synaptics.enable = true;
  };

  super = import <nixpkgs/nixos/modules/services/x11/xserver.nix> args // basic;
in {
  options = super.options;
  disabledModules = [ "services/x11/xserver.nix" ];
  config = lib.recursiveUpdate super.config {
    services.xserver.config = "";
  };
}
```

Here's the (cut down) output from nix-repl:

```
nix-repl> evalConfig = import <nixpkgs/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix>

nix-repl> basic = { config.services.xserver = { enable = true; synaptics.enable = true; }; }
nix-repl> result2 = evalConfig { modules = [ basic ./wrapper2.nix ]; }
nix-repl> result2.config.services.xserver.config
"# Automatically enable the synaptics driver... // services/x11/hardware/synaptics.nix
Section "ServerFlags"... EndSection // services/x11/xserver.nix

nix-repl> result3 = evalConfig { modules = [ ./wrapper3.nix ]; }
nix-repl> result3.config.services.xserver.config
"# Automatically enable the synaptics driver... // services/x11/hardware/synaptics.nix only
```

I think that the `config` in your initial wrappers are being merged somehow with `config` that don't have the `services/x11/xserver.nix` module disabled, and so your changes are just getting overridden again.

Unless anyone else has a more helpful answer for your question here then it might be helpful for you to ask in the NixOS IRC channel, otherwise you could always look through the NixOS module system [source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/lib/modules.nix) to try and work out how best to handle overriding the `xserver.nix` `config` (the source is a bit of a headache at first but once you get your head round the recursion it is not too bad).